# Multi Threading with Synchronize in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

```
    Using webClient = New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim owner = ""
        Try
            owner = webClient.DownloadString("http://" + CurrentBlog.Domain + "/test.php")
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        appendToTextFile(CurrentBlog.Domain + checkdomainsowner(owner) + Microsoft.VisualBasic.vbNewLine, "gooddoorway.txt")
    End Using
```

I want to run that using threadpool.

A way to do so would be

```
    Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        Sub()
            Using webClient = New System.Net.WebClient
                Dim owner = ""
                Try
                    owner = webClient.DownloadString("http://" + CurrentBlog.Domain + "/test.php")
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
                appendToTextFile(CurrentBlog.Domain + checkdomainsowner(owner) + Microsoft.VisualBasic.vbNewLine, "gooddoorway.txt")
            End Using
        End Sub)
```

The catch is I want `appendToTextFile(CurrentBlog.Domain + checkdomainsowner(owner) + Microsoft.VisualBasic.vbNewLine, "gooddoorway.txt")` to be synchronized to main thread.

What would be the easy way to do it? I do not want to use any control.invoke because the code should run independent of any control. I do not want to use global variable because my TA said it's a bad thing.

Comment: Raise an event.  If there is no form then nobody cares.  If there is one then the form's event handler can do what it needs to do, including calling BeginInvoke().

Comment: code sample? what do you mean?

Comment: What are you asking?  Don't know how to implement events?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c6bkaht%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @JimThio see the code sample on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703732/getting-web-page-after-calling-downloadstringasync

Comment: I need simpler solution. I ended up implementing a global variable just for this sort of thing.